# How do I fix the 401 Unauthorized error with Laravel Sanctum and React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I have the following set-up:

- Laravel running with Homestead
- Domain `laravel-api.test` pointing to my Homestead environment
- React (npx create-react-app) running locally with a custom HOST `app.laravel-api.test:3000`

---

**Laravel**

In my routes `(routes/api.php)` I added two routes:

```
Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('books', [App\Http\Controllers\BookController::class, 'list']);
```

In my `config/cors.php` I added:

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

In my `.env` I added the following:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.laravel-api.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app.laravel-api.test:3000
```

---

**React**

In React I made a function to easily send Axios requests:

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://laravel-api.test",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default apiClient;
```

Then I made a submit function for my login form:

```
const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    apiClient.get("sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
      apiClient
        .post("api/login", {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

- Now my request for `sanctum/csrf-cookie` is going well and I'll receive Cookies.
- The request for `login` is also going great and it will return the User.

---

**Problem**

But the problem now is that I have made a button to request a list of books (`/api/books`). The Request is sending, but I get an `401 Unauthorized` error with a `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` response.

I have read a lot of forums, but I cannot find my situation and no answer. What can I try? How can i debug the sanctum and find out why I am not authenticated.

Is it the cookie? Is it the hostname?

```
import React from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api";

interface Book {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

const Books = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = React.useState<Book[]>([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    apiClient
      .get("/api/books")
      .then((response) => {
        setBooks(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  const bookList = books.map((book) => <li key={book.id}>{book.title}</li>);

  return <ul>{bookList}</ul>;
};

export default Books;
```

Comment: That is one problem i have been trying to solve for some months now.
this issue had made me to abandon the project for a while because i couldn't move forward because of the reasonless 401 error.

recently i have comeback to the project and found my self looking for solution.

i also had to ask a question about my observation https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/36419.

so far no solution yet but i will drop when i get one and also don't forget to drop urs as well if found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was my cache for config I had to clear each time I changed my .env file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that first you need to set up your hosts different, your react app should have the main domain **laravel-api.test** without the port and your backend should be: **api.laravel-api.test**

in your .env you should have this:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.laravel-api.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=laravel-api.test
```

also in your backend: /config/cors.php , change the support_credentials to true :

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```