# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Network Error using nextjs and laravel-breeze

Tags: next.js, laravel-breeze

to go a bit fast in my development I used breeze and the fontend nextjs (https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next) recommended on the official site but I'm having this problem. I don't know what TO DO.

Cordially

I tried several solutions read on the web but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at ([How do I fix the 401 Unauthorized error with Laravel Sanctum and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384766/how-do-i-fix-the-401-unauthorized-error-with-laravel-sanctum-and-react)).

I just had to clear the cache after modifying the .env file

```
php artisan cache:clear
```